# Tem como ignorar uma página no log do apache?

Tags: ajax, apache, log

Estou desenvolvendo uma página a qual fará consulta permanente via Ajax, acontece que o Log de acesso do Apache vai encher muito rapidamente e isso me traz um problema de espaço no servidor, fiquei imaginando como tratar isso, uma solução seria ignorar somente a página onde está o Ajax, pois não vejo necessidade de monitora-la.

Sei que podemos fazer múltiplos logs no apache, mas não sei se podemos ignorar ou escolher determinadas pastas ou páginas do servidor.

Seria possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseado nos [DOCS](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html), na secção "Conditional Logs" podemos ver:

```
# Não incluir nos logs caso a requisição venha do ip abaixo
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" dontlog
# Não incluir nos logs o request abaixo, este é o que tu queres
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/robots\.txt$" dontlog
# Incluir tudo o resto
CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!dontlog
```

Colocas o que precisas no teu .htaccess

Comment: hum... exatamente o que preciso